# Não consigo selecionar um item da listbox e pegar as demais informações no Banco de Dados partir desse item selecionado

Tags: c#, winforms

A ideia do software é selecionar um nome na combobox (cmb_nomeGu) e com isso jogar na listbox (lst_resultado) todas as datas encontradas que contém o nome escolhido, para posteriormente, clicar nas datas existentes para buscar a ultima informação, que é o resumo da ocorrencia (txt_ocorrencia).
O problema acontece quando tento clicar em uma data na listbox para buscar as demais informações no banco de dados a partir da data selecionada, para após isso preencher a caixa de texto (txt_ocorrencias) com a informação encontrada.
O erro que aparece é: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

[image: Form Pesquisar]

```
OperacaoBanco operacao = new OperacaoBanco();
MySqlDataReader dados;



private void lst_resultado_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cmb_nomeGu.Text != "")
    {        
        try
           {
           string dataServico = "", ocorrenciaObtida = "";
           dataServico = lst_resultado.SelectedItem.ToString();
           //MessageBox.Show(dataServico);
           dados = operacao.Select("SELECT ds_ocorrencia FROM tb_livro2018 WHERE dt_servico = '" + dataServico + "'");

           grp_resumo.Visible = true;

           while (dados.Read())
              {                  
              ocorrenciaObtida = Convert.ToString(dados[0]);
              txt_ocorrencias.Text = ocorrenciaObtida;
              }
           }
        catch (Exception erro)
           {
           MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível realizar a pesquisa \n Erro:" + erro);
           }
        finally
           {
           Connection.fecharConexao();
           }
        }



}
```

[image: erro]

SEGUE ABAIXO AS CLASSES PARA CONEXÃO E OPERAÇÃO NO BANCO

**CONEXAO**

```
class Connection
{
    public static MySqlConnection conexao = null;
    private String stringconnection = "server=**********;User Id = ********; password=********;database=*************";

    public void tentarAbrirConexaoLocal()
    {
        conexao = new MySqlConnection();
        conexao.ConnectionString = stringconnection;
        conexao.Open();
    }

    public Connection()
    {
        try
        {
            tentarAbrirConexaoLocal();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Não foi possível validar seu acesso.Tente novamente.");
        }
     }
    public static MySqlConnection getConexao()
    {
        new Connection();
        return conexao;
    }
    public static void fecharConexao()
    {
        conexao.Close();
    }
}
```

**CLASSE OPERAÇÃO**

```
class OperacaoBanco
{
    private MySqlCommand TemplateMethod(String query)
    {
        MySqlConnection Conexao = Connection.getConexao();
        MySqlCommand Comando = new MySqlCommand(query, Conexao);

        try
        {
            Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return Comando;
        }
        catch
        {
            return Comando;
        }
    }

    public MySqlDataReader Select(String query)
    {
        MySqlDataReader dadosObtidos = TemplateMethod(query).ExecuteReader();
        return dadosObtidos;
    }

    public Boolean Insert(String query)
    {
        MySqlConnection Conexao = Connection.getConexao();
        MySqlCommand Comando = new MySqlCommand(query, Conexao);

        try
        {
            Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Boolean Update(String query)
    {
        MySqlConnection Conexao = Connection.getConexao();
        MySqlCommand Comando = new MySqlCommand(query, Conexao);

        try
        {
            Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public Boolean Delete(String query)
    {
        MySqlConnection Conexao = Connection.getConexao();
        MySqlCommand Comando = new MySqlCommand(query, Conexao);

        try
        {
            Comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `NullReferenceException` significa que está a utilizar um objeto que está a `null`. Qual a linha de código em que esse erro acontece ?

Comment: Segundo a exceção retornada, o erro é na linha 222. Outra coisa vc esta tratando a data corretamente? Percebi que vc está usando MySql, e datas são tratadas neste formato `AAAA/MM/DD`.

Comment: Eu as troquei, coloquei tudo em string e no formato dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: a linha 222 é referente ao codigo: 'dataServico = lst_resultado.SelectedItem.ToString();'

Comment: Troca SelectedItem por SelectedValue ou SelectedText

Comment: Testei com o SelectedItem e SelectedValue... com os dois o erro para, porém só busca a primeira informação (txt_ocorrencia) do primeiro item na lista, mesmo eu clicando nos outros. Em resumo, o campo 'Resumo' só é preenchido com o 1º indice, independentemente do item selecionado.

Comment: Olhando melhor aqui.... parece que todas as datas listadas na listbox estão como um único indice...

Comment: @JulioCezarAlmeida Não consegui entender direito o que você quer fazer. Sua pergunta original descreve que precisa selecionar dados no banco com um item da listBox. Lendo seus comentários parece que existe um outro problema que não está nada claro (erro de banco/lógica da linguagem/formulário/outro fator). Pode ser mais específico ?